how to expand date in python?
I have a dataset:
Line    Style No             Loading date
G01 DDS23-00648-1101(BR)     05/08/2024
G01 RG322F2633               09/08/2024
G01 RG322F2633               17/08/2024
G01 RG322F2633               24/08/2024

I want to expand the loading date like this:
   Line              Style No Loading_date
0   G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)   05/08/2024
1   G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)   06/08/2024
2   G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)   07/08/2024
3   G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)   08/08/2024
4   G01            RG322F2633   09/08/2024
5   G01            RG322F2633   10/08/2024
6   G01            RG322F2633   11/08/2024
7   G01            RG322F2633   12/08/2024
8   G01            RG322F2633   13/08/2024
9   G01            RG322F2633   14/08/2024
10  G01            RG322F2633   15/08/2024
11  G01            RG322F2633   16/08/2024
12  G01            RG322F2633   17/08/2024
13  G01            RG322F2633   18/08/2024
14  G01            RG322F2633   19/08/2024
15  G01            RG322F2633   20/08/2024
16  G01            RG322F2633   21/08/2024
17  G01            RG322F2633   22/08/2024
18  G01            RG322F2633   23/08/2024
19  G01            RG322F2633   24/08/2024

I tried using this but it did not work. please help me!
df1.set_index('Loading_date').groupby(['Line', 'Style No']).resample('1D').ffill().reset_index()

expected result

If need expand datetimes per Line groups change your code with solution bellow:
df1['Loading_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Loading_date'], dayfirst=True)

df = (df1.set_index('Loading_date')
         .groupby(['Line'])
         .resample('1D')
         .ffill()
         .droplevel(0)
         .reset_index()
         .reindex(df1.columns, axis=1))

df['Loading_date'] = df['Loading_date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print (df)
   Line              Style No Loading_date
0   G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)   05/08/2024
1   G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)   06/08/2024
2   G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)   07/08/2024
3   G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)   08/08/2024
4   G01            RG322F2633   09/08/2024
5   G01            RG322F2633   10/08/2024
6   G01            RG322F2633   11/08/2024
7   G01            RG322F2633   12/08/2024
8   G01            RG322F2633   13/08/2024
9   G01            RG322F2633   14/08/2024
10  G01            RG322F2633   15/08/2024
11  G01            RG322F2633   16/08/2024
12  G01            RG322F2633   17/08/2024
13  G01            RG322F2633   18/08/2024
14  G01            RG322F2633   19/08/2024
15  G01            RG322F2633   20/08/2024
16  G01            RG322F2633   21/08/2024
17  G01            RG322F2633   22/08/2024
18  G01            RG322F2633   23/08/2024
19  G01            RG322F2633   24/08/2024


HI jezrael,
thanks for supporting. However, there is an error:
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels.

@ĐứcHoàngNguyễn - there is problem with duplicated dates per Lines, how working if add df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(['Line','Loading_date']) before my solution? Btw, is possible share complete your data e.g. in csv or excel by dropbox, gdocs or similar? Because this is data related issue.

Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {'Line': ['G01', 'G01', 'G01', 'G01'], 'Style No': ['DDS23-00648-1101(BR)', 'RG322F2633', 'RG322F2633', 'RG322F2633'], 'Loading date': ['05/08/2024', '09/08/2024', '17/08/2024', '24/08/2024']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
  Line              Style No Loading date
0  G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)   05/08/2024
1  G01            RG322F2633   09/08/2024
2  G01            RG322F2633   17/08/2024
3  G01            RG322F2633   24/08/2024

Code
fmt = '%d/%m/%Y'
df['Loading date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Loading date'], format=fmt)
out = (df.resample(rule='D', on='Loading date').first()
         .ffill().reset_index()[df.columns]
)
out['Loading date'] = out['Loading date'].dt.strftime(fmt)

out:
   Line              Style No Loading date
0   G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)   05/08/2024
1   G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)   06/08/2024
2   G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)   07/08/2024
...
17  G01            RG322F2633   22/08/2024
18  G01            RG322F2633   23/08/2024
19  G01            RG322F2633   24/08/2024


thanks for sharing a dictionary form of the dataframe - makes it super easy to reproduce

Hi Bro,
my raw data contains 4249 rows. But after running your suggested codes, the result contains only 148 rows.

import pandas as pd

data = {'Line': ['G01', 'G01', 'G01', 'G01'],
        'Style No': ['DDS23-00648-1101(BR)', 'RG322F2633', 'RG322F2633', 'RG322F2633'],
        'Loading date': ['05/08/1990', '09/08/1990', '17/08/1990', '24/08/1990']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Loading date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Loading date'],format = '%d/%m/%Y')
'''
  Line              Style No Loading date
0  G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)   1990-08-05
1  G01            RG322F2633   1990-08-09
2  G01            RG322F2633   1990-08-17
3  G01            RG322F2633   1990-08-24
'''
df.set_index('Loading date',inplace = True)
'''
             Line              Style No
Loading date                           
1990-08-05    G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)
1990-08-09    G01            RG322F2633
1990-08-17    G01            RG322F2633
1990-08-24    G01            RG322F2633
'''
full_date_range = pd.date_range(start = df.index.min(), end = df.index.max(), freq = 'D')

df = df.reindex(full_date_range).ffill()
'''
           Line              Style No
1990-08-05  G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)
1990-08-06  G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)
1990-08-07  G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)
1990-08-08  G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)
1990-08-09  G01            RG322F2633
1990-08-10  G01            RG322F2633
....
1990-08-23  G01            RG322F2633
1990-08-24  G01            RG322F2633
'''
df.reset_index(inplace =True)
df.rename(columns ={'index' : 'Loading_date'},inplace=True)
print(df)
'''
  Loading_date Line              Style No
0    1990-08-05  G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)
1    1990-08-06  G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)
2    1990-08-07  G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)
3    1990-08-08  G01  DDS23-00648-1101(BR)
4    1990-08-09  G01            RG322F2633
5    1990-08-10  G01            RG322F2633
6    1990-08-11  G01            RG322F2633
7    1990-08-12  G01            RG322F2633
8    1990-08-13  G01            RG322F2633
9    1990-08-14  G01            RG322F2633
10   1990-08-15  G01            RG322F2633
11   1990-08-16  G01            RG322F2633
12   1990-08-17  G01            RG322F2633
13   1990-08-18  G01            RG322F2633
14   1990-08-19  G01            RG322F2633
15   1990-08-20  G01            RG322F2633
16   1990-08-21  G01            RG322F2633
17   1990-08-22  G01            RG322F2633
18   1990-08-23  G01            RG322F2633
19   1990-08-24  G01            RG322F2633
'''

